# Function in class keeps returning errors (converting type void or Student to float, or directory not found)

Tags: c++, class, templates, c++17, overloading

I am trying to return the average of a sum of integers as a float. I am trying to keep everything in the header, and only call functions in main. However, calculateAverage keeps returning errors.

```
/tmp/ccmVBZhQ.o: In function `Student::calculateAverage()':                     
grade.cpp:(.text._ZN7Student16calculateAverageEv[_ZN7Student16calculateAverageEv
]+0x2f): undefined reference to `std::iterator_traits<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterat
or<int*, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > >::value_type reduce<__gnu_cxx
::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > >(__gnu_cxx::
__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, __gnu_cxx::__n
ormal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >)'                 
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status                                      
./vpl_execution: line 22: ./a.out: No such file or directory
```

I have been trying to figure this out for over a week, and I need some help here. I am trying to set the float for 'average', but among other errors I have encountered, includes trying to convert the type Student or void to float.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <numeric>
#include <functional>
using namespace std;
template< class InputIt >
typename std::iterator_traits<InputIt>::value_type
    reduce( InputIt first, InputIt last );
class College
{
    private:
        static string principal_name;  // principal_name is common for all the students
    public:
        static void setPrincipalName(string name)
        {
            principal_name = name;
        }
       static string getPrincipalName()
        {
            return principal_name;
        }
};
//Initialize the static principal_name variable with value "John" here

string College::principal_name = "John";


class Student
{
    private:
        vector<int> gradesVec;
        int id,stdId,markElement;
        string name,studentName,reqName;
        string return1 = "Student Name : ",return2 = "Student ID : ",return3 = "Principal Name : ",return4 = "Average : ",return5 = "Grade : ";
        string prompt1 = "Enter Student ID : ",prompt2 = "Enter Student Name : ",prompt3 = "Enter the five subject marks : ";
        float average;
        char grade;
        College cObj;
        float marks[5];
    public:
    
    void promptID()  {
        cout << prompt1 << endl;
    }
    void promptStdName() {
        cout << prompt2 << endl;
    }
    void promptMarks()  {
        cout << prompt3 << endl;
    }
    void nameRequest()  {
        cin >> studentName;
    }
    void idRequest()    {
        cin >> stdId;
    }
    void reqMarks() {
        cin >> markElement;
    }
    void setMarksVector()   {
        gradesVec.push_back(markElement);
    }
    void getNameRequest()   {
        
    }
    void getIdRequest() {
        
    }
    void getMarksVector()   {
        
    }
    void getStudentDetails();
    void calculateAverage() {
        average = (reduce(gradesVec.begin(),gradesVec.end())) / (gradesVec.size());

    };
    void findGrade()    {
        
    }
    void displayStudentDetails();
    void setId(int id)
    {
        this->id=id;
    }
    int getId()
    {
        return id;
    }
    void setAverage(float average)
    {
        this->average=average;
    }
    int getAverage()
    {
        return average;
    }
    void setName(string n)
    {
        this->name=n;
    }
    string getName()
    {
        return name;
    }
    void setMarks(float m[])
    {
        for(int i=0; i<4;i++)
            this->marks[i]=m[i];
    }
    float* getMarks()
    {
        return marks;
    }
    void setGrade(char g)
    {
        grade=g;
    }
    char getGrade()
    {
        return grade;
    }
    College getCollegeObject()
    {
        return cObj;
    }

};
int main()  //DO NOT change the 'main' signature
{
    //Fill code here



int stdId, grade2;
float grade1, avg;
string studentName,grade;

Student student;

student.promptID();
student.idRequest();
student.setId(stdId);
student.promptStdName();
student.nameRequest();
student.setName(studentName);
student.promptMarks();
student.reqMarks();
student.setMarksVector();
student.reqMarks();
student.setMarksVector();
student.reqMarks();
student.setMarksVector();
student.reqMarks();
student.setMarksVector();
student.reqMarks();
student.setMarksVector();
student.calculateAverage();


student.setId(stdId);
student.setName(studentName);



return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your code has different errors then what is shown: [https://ideone.com/BYHT91#cmperr](https://ideone.com/BYHT91#cmperr)

Comment: Sorry. I tried to include the minimum amount of code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason of the error that you are referring to is that the template function `reduce()`:

```
template< class InputIt >
typename std::iterator_traits<InputIt>::value_type
    reduce( InputIt first, InputIt last );
```

is not defined.

It seems you mean:

```
template< class InputIt >
typename std::iterator_traits<InputIt>::value_type
reduce( InputIt first, InputIt last )
{
    return std::reduce( first, last );
}
```

And in the member function `calculateAverage()`, you need to use a qualified name to avoid ambiguity:

```
void calculateAverage() {
    average = (::reduce(gradesVec.begin(),gradesVec.end())) / ( float )(gradesVec.size());
}
```

Here is a demonstration program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <numeric>

template< class InputIt >
typename std::iterator_traits<InputIt>::value_type
    reduce( InputIt first, InputIt last )
    {
        return std::reduce( first, last );
    }

class Student
{
public:
    std::vector<int> gradesVec;
    float average;
    void calculateAverage() {
        average = (::reduce(gradesVec.begin(),gradesVec.end())) / ( float )(gradesVec.size());

    }
};    

int main()
{
    Student student = { { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 } };
    student.calculateAverage();

    std::cout << "student.average = " << student.average << '\n';
}
```

The program output is

```
student.average = 5.5
```

I think the template function `::reduce()` is redundant. You could directly call the standard algorithm `std::reduce()` from the member function.

Comment: The error I get from this is:

' 'grade.cpp:11:12: error: ‘reduce’ is not a member of ‘std’ '

along with more related to that error.

Comment: @PeterSmedskjaer See the demonstration program in my answer.

Comment: @PeterSmedskjaer Are you compiling for C++17 or later? And do you have `#include <numeric>` in your code?

Comment: Yes, I am compiling in C++17 with IBMs online compiler. And yes, I did include numeric. I am perplexed by these errors.

Comment: @PeterSmedskjaer Try the demonstration program. Then use it as a basic code for your program.

Comment: I tried implementing your code. Same error as before.

Comment: @PeterSmedskjaer Please copy and paste the code as is. It compiles successfully.

Comment: I tried it in Visual Studio 2022. Errors were returned:

Build started...
1>------ Build started: Project: stackoverflow example, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>stackoverflow example.cpp
1>C:\Users\Cepter\source\repos\stackoverflow example\stackoverflow example.cpp(10,17): error C2039: 'reduce': is not a member of 'std'
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.32.31326\include\numeric(23): message : see declaration of 'std'
1>Done building project "stackoverflow example.vcxproj" -- FAILED.

Comment: @PeterSmedskjaer You need in properties of the project to set the C++ language to the last release. It seems that by default it compiles your program as a C++14 program.

Comment: I caught that too. The error I get instead is: Build started...
1>------ Build started: Project: Project3, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>Source.cpp
1>C:\Users\Cepter\source\repos\Project3\Source.cpp(10,17): error C2039: 'reduce': is not a member of 'std'
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.32.31326\include\numeric(23): message : see declaration of 'std'
1>Done building project "Project3.vcxproj" -- FAILED.

Comment: @PeterSmedskjaer I call std::reduce using MS VS 2019 and there was no any problem. Either you did not set in the properties of your project the last release of the C++ compiler or you doing something wrong.  Also check whether you included the header <numeric>

Comment: I have it kinda working now, but it wont return the last values.